# Use NSPredicate to filter by index

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

Basically, what I want to do is this:

```
NSArray *objectsAtIndex1 = @[[@[@"Foo", @"Bar"] objectAtIndex:1]];
```

but using `NSPredicate` instead, so it would look something like this (however this is not working):

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF[1] != null"]
NSArray *objectsAtIndex1 = [@[@"Foo", @"Bar"] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]
```

And of course, *@"Foo"* and *@"Bar"* are in reality unknown values (and could even be  dictionaries or numbers). Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: It's unclear if you want to use something similar like this: https://gist.github.com/tomohisa/3069721 or really need a `NSPredicate` (for a Query ?)

Comment: why do you need _predicate_ while `objectAtIndex:` can do the job for you? is there any special advantage you are expecting from a _predicate_ in this case?

Comment: @holex The reason why `NSPredicate` is needed in my case is that the code should be able to handle all sorts of filtering, not only filtering by index. So it would be nice to not have to rewrite hundreds lines of code or so just because of this single case.

Comment: You can't do "SELF[1] != null". `SELF` is "Foo" or "Bar", not an array. An element of an array can't be `nil`. So no, you can't use `NSPredicate`, which does `evaluateWithObject:` for each element of the array. If you need all sorts of filtering, use `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:`.

Comment: Create an extension of NSArray: `-(NSArray *)arrayFromIndex:(NSInteger)index { if ([self count] > index) { return @[self[index]]; } else { return nil; //or return @[]}  }` seems to be an easier way to do so. Then it's `NSArray *objectsAtIndex1 = [ @[@"Foo", @"Bar"] arrayFromIndex:1];`?

Comment: @Larme Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm not so concerned about getting out of bounds of the array, that will not happen in my case since the array is used to populate a `UITableView` and the index is an `indexPath.row`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using the `predicateWithBlock:` method on `NSPredicate` like this:

```
NSArray *fooBarArray = @[@"Foo", @"Bar"];
NSUInteger index = 1;
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return [fooBarArray indexOfObject:evaluatedObject] == index;
}];
NSArray *objectsAtIndex1 = [fooBarArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

One caveat is however that the objects in fooBar-array needs to be unique for this to work, which is not perfect.

Comment: Alternatively, get the object at `index` once and return `evaluatedObject == objectAtIndex`. Predicate format: `"SELF = %@", objectAtIndex`. This avoids many `indexOfObject:`s.